# Meteor, Delay updating the database but show the change in the page

Tags: meteor

I want to delay the call to update the database for a minute or two, so if the user wants to do a edit she can. something like the comment in the stack Overflow, that you can't do an edit after a while.

I did update the Template.CurrentData in the submit event, but it was not reactive. and when user refreshes it goes away.

```
  Template.currentData().comments.push({ text : event.target.textValue.value})
```

I don't let client side to update the database.

maybe update the minimongo and disable updating to DB somehow??? then with Meteor.timeOut call the server method that updates the database??

Comment: But delaying it will means that noone can see it during that period of time, what is your use case?

Comment: In case the element has a creation date (and it seems like it should in your case), simply make sure that the attempted edit is within your set time limit and if not, reject it. No need to prevent its persistence to the DB. You can implement this as an allow/deny rule or in a method.

Comment: I wanted to save some request to server as well. but what you are suggesting is easiest thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XY problem here. What you want to do is save the submit date, and check against it while attempting an update. Here is an example using `allow` hooks.

```
// initial insert
Comments.insert({
  content: 'Sono un gatto moretto.',
  createdAt: new Date()
});

Comments.allow({
  update: function (userId, document, fields, modifier) {
    const twoMinutes = moment(document.createdAt).add(2, 'minutes');
    if (moment().isAfter(twoMinutes)) {
      return false;  // reject if it's after two minutes.
    }
    // I'm sure you'll want to do other checks here
  }
});
```